# Adding a custom command to gitk's commit right-click menu

Tags: git, customization, gitk

How do I add a custom command to gitk's menu shown when right-clicking a commit? The command I want to add specifically is `git revert`, but I'm hoping for a generic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A menu item for `git-revert` was added recently to gitk:

```
commit f74455ab216bdc4f21a733f75ddd6974634c5df1
Merge: 8d97506 76bf6ff
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster@pobox.com>
Date:   Mon May 13 07:51:41 2013 -0700

[...]
      gitk: Add menu item for reverting commits
```

Just clone the git sources from `git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git`

Answer (score 1):

gitk is a tcl script.  You could simply add commands to it (assuming you know a little about tcl).

Comment: I could see doing that as a last resort. But if it's possible to do it via configuration, I'd rather do that. So let's wait a bit to see if someone can tell if there's a config option to do this.

Comment: I agree with you it would be nice just to plug a script in as I do not know tcl very well.